# Program closes when executed (Bathc)

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

So this is supposed to check if this files exist in %HOMEPATH% but it only can be executed between 10:05 and 13:15

```
@echo off & cls
color 8f
set HORA = %time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
if %HORA% GEQ 1005 (
    if %HORA% LEQ 1315 (
        cd %HOMEPATH%
        if EXIST Desktop (
            echo Desktop hi es >> registre.log
            ) ELSE ( echo Desktop no hi es >> registre.log
            )
        if EXIST Music (
            echo Music hi es > registre.log
            ) ELSE ( echo Music no hi es > registre.log
            )
        if EXIST Documents (
            echo Mis Documentos hi es > registre.log
            ) ELSE ( Mis Documentos no hi es > registre.log
            )
        if EXIST Downloads (
            echo Descarregues hi es > registre.log
            ) ELSE ( Descarregues no hi es > registre.log
            )
        type registre.log
        pause > nul
        del registre.log
    )
)
echo Ara no es pot executar
pause
exit
```

When i open the file it closes inmediatly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
          v.......................... space included in variable value 
set HORA = %time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
        ^...........................  space included in variable name
```

So, to reference your variable you need `%HORA %`. Better change to

```
set "HORA=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%"
```

No spaces and the quotes, that are not included in the value, will also prevent the inclusion of aditional spaces at the end of the line.